# How does dynamic binding happens in JVM?

Tags: java, dynamic, binding

Dynamic binding in Java happens at run time for overriding functions. I would like to know how it happens internally (like in C++, virtual functions/table is used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All non-final non-private, not-static methods in Java are virtual

Comment: @dkatzel:sounds good, gr8. May I know how these virtual methods are treated in Java. Is it similar to that of using Virtual table concept?

Comment: The Java Language Spec is very clear. JLS 8.4.8 discusses method overriding http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8 and JLS 15.2.5  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5 discusses how the most specific method is chosen.
Hopefully that's a good start.  There might be other sections that are useful as well.

Answer (score 8):

Well as mentioned above, In Java all non-final non-private, not-static methods are virtual, which means any method which can be overridden in a child class is virtual.

But In order to understand how JVM handle it internally let us take below code example

```
public class OverridingInternalExample {

    private static class Mammal {
        public void speak() { System.out.println("ohlllalalalalalaoaoaoa"); }
    }

    private static class Human extends Mammal {

        @Override
        public void speak() { System.out.println("Hello"); }

        // Valid overload of speak
        public void speak(String language) {
            if (language.equals("Hindi")) System.out.println("Namaste");
            else System.out.println("Hello");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return "Human Class"; }

    }

    //  Code below contains the output and and bytecode of the method calls
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mammal anyMammal = new Mammal();
        anyMammal.speak();  // Output - ohlllalalalalalaoaoaoa
        // 10: invokevirtual #4 // Method org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal.speak:()V

        Mammal humanMammal = new Human();
        humanMammal.speak(); // Output - Hello
        // 23: invokevirtual #4 // Method org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal.speak:()V

        Human human = new Human();
        human.speak(); // Output - Hello
        // 36: invokevirtual #7 // Method org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Human.speak:()V

        human.speak("Hindi"); // Output - Namaste
        // 42: invokevirtual #9 // Method org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Human.speak:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    }
}
```

We can see bytecode for `anyMammal.speak()` and `humanMammal.speak()` are same ( `invokevirtual #4 // Method org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal.speak:()V`) because according to compiler both methods are called on Mammal reference.

So now the question comes if both method calls have same bytecode then how does JVM know which method to call?

Well, the answer is hidden in the bytecode itself and it is `invokevirtual` instruction, according to JVM specification

> invokevirtual invokes an instance method of an object, dispatching on the (virtual) type of the object. This is the normal method dispatch in the Java programming language.

JVM uses the `invokevirtual` instruction to invoke Java equivalent of the C++ virtual methods. In C++ if we want to override one method in another class we need to declare it as `virtual`, But in Java, all methods are virtual by default (except final and static methods) because we can override every method in the child class.

Operation `invokevirtual` accepts a pointer to method reference call ( `#4` an index into the constant pool)

```
invokevirtual #4   // Method org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal.speak:()V
```

And that method reference #4 again refers to a method name and Class reference

```
#4 = Methodref   #2.#27   // org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal.speak:()V
#2 = Class   #25   // org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal
#25 = Utf8   org/programming/mitra/exercises/OverridingInternalExample$Mammal
#27 = NameAndType   #35:#17   // speak:()V
#35 = Utf8   speak
#17 = Utf8
```

All these references combinedly used to get a reference to a method and class in which the method is to be found. This is also mentioned in JVM Specification

> The Java virtual machine does not mandate any particular internal structure for objects 4.

And the bookmark 4 states

> In some of Oracle’s implementations of the Java virtual machine, a reference to a class instance is a pointer to a handle that is itself a pair of pointers: one to a table containing the methods of the object and a pointer to the Class object that represents the type of the object, and the other to the memory allocated from the heap for the object data.

It means every reference variable holds two hidden pointers

1. A pointer to a table which again holds methods of the object and a pointer to the Class object. e.g. [speak(), speak(String) Class object]
2. A pointer to the memory allocated on the heap for that object’s data e.g. values of instance variables.

But again the question comes, how `invokevirtual` internally do this? Well, no one can answer this because it depends on JVM implementation and it varies from JVM to JVM.

And from above statements, we can conclude that an object reference indirectly holds a reference/pointer to a table which holds all the method references of that object. Java has borrowed this concept from C++ and this table is known by various names which such as [virtual method table ( **VMT** ), virtual function table ( **vftable** ), virtual table ( **vtable** ), dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

We can not sure of how `vtable` is implemented in Java because it is JVM dependent. But we can expect that it will be following the same strategy as C++ where `vtable` is an array like structure which holds method names and their references on array indices. And whenever JVM try to execute a virtual method it always asks the `vtable` for it address.

There is only one `vtable` per class means it is unique and same for all objects of a class similar to `Class` object. I have discussed more on `Class` object in my articles [Why an outer Java class can’t be static](https://programmingmitra.com/2016/10/why-outer-java-class-cant-be-static.html) and [Why Java is Purely Object-Oriented Language Or Why Not](https://programmingmitra.com/2016/06/why-java-is-purely-object-oriented-or-why-not.html).

So there is only one `vtable` for `Object` class which contains all 11 methods (if we don't count registerNatives) and references to their respective method bodies.

[image: vtable-of-object]

When JVM loads the `Mammal` class into memory it creates a `Class` object for it and creates a `vtable` which contains all the methods from the vtable of Object class with the same references (Because `Mammal` is not overriding any method from Object) and adds a new entry for `speak` method.

[image: vtable-human]

Now here comes the turn of `Human` class and now JVM will copy all entries from the `vtable` of `Mammal` class to the `vtable` of `Human` and adds a new entry for the overloaded version of `speak(String)`.

JVM knows that `Human` class has overridden two methods one is `toString()` from `Object` and second is `speck()` from `Mammal` . Now instead of creating new entries for these methods with updated references. JVM will modify the references to the already present methods on the same index where they were present earlier and will keep the same method names.

[image]

The `invokevirtual` causes the JVM to treat the value at method reference `#4`, not as an address but as the name of a method to look up in the `vtable` for the current object.

I hope now it would have become a little bit clear that how the JVM mixes `constant pool` entries and `vtable` to conclude which method it is going to call.

You can read more on my article [How Does JVM Handle Method Overloading and Overriding Internally](https://programmingmitra.com/2017/05/how-does-jvm-handle-method-overriding-internally.html).

Answer (score 0):

The JVM specification describes how a JVM must resolve virtual methods here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual

This part is most pertinent:

> Otherwise, if C has a superclass, this same lookup procedure is performed recursively using the direct superclass of C; the method to be invoked is the result of the recursive invocation of this lookup procedure.

Exactly how that recursion takes place depends on how the JVM writer implemented this.  Here is a link describing how it's done in OpenJDK (includes a link to C++ code):
https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/VirtualCalls